# How to seperate numeric values from string using regex in python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have a string mixed with numbers and words. I want to be able to extract the numeric values from the string as tokens.

For example,

```
input
str = "Score 1 and 2 sometimes, often 1 and 1/2, or 2.5 or 3 and 1/3." should ideally 

output, 
Score -> word
1 -> number 
and -> word
2 -> number 
...
1 and 1/2 -> number (this group should stay together as number)
or -> word
2.5 -> number
...
3 and 1/3 -> number
```

I could solve the problem partly by using regex as follows,

```
rule 1:
re.findall(r'\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*', str1) and 
rule 2:
re.findall(r'(?:\s*\d* and \d+\/\d+\s*)', str1)
```

It partly works. I could not put these together to solve the problem.
I tried this,

```
re.findall(r'(?:\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*)|(?:\s*\d* and \d+\/\d+\s*)', str1)
```

Can anyone please help and show how I could put the rules together and get the result?

Comment: Try `r'\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?(?:\s+and\s+\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?)?'`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, I also picking '1 and 2.' Expected is, 1, 2 as separate numbers, as well as '1 and 1/2' as single number.

Comment: If you need to add groups, do that, see https://regex101.com/r/6js6eo/1. To get the full match with `re.findall`, also wrap the whole pattern with brackets, https://regex101.com/r/6js6eo/2

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear. It gives, Score <1 and 2> sometimes, often <1 and 1/2>, or <2.5> or <3 and 1/3>.

The first <1 and 2> was expected to be separate numbers.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/7G7aVa. It yields `[('1', '2'), ('1', '1/2'), ('2.5', ''), ('3', '1/3')]`. What do you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your help Wiktor. However, expected is, <1>, <2>, <1 and 1/2>, <2.5>, <3 and 1/3>. Please check the 'output' section in the original question above for detail.

Comment: So, https://ideone.com/3l2kQ5?

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! It worked great. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

text = "Score 1 and 2 sometimes, often 1 and 1/2, or 2.5 or 3 and 1/3."

matches = re.findall(r'((\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?)(?:\s+and\s+(\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?))?)', text)

result = []
for x,y,z in matches:
    if '/' in x:
        result.append(x)
    else:
        result.extend(filter(lambda x: x!="", [y,z]))

print( result )
# => ['1', '2', '1 and 1/2', '2.5', '3 and 1/3']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3l2kQ5). Here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6js6eo/3).

Details:

- The regex contains three capturing groups, around it as a whole, and two groups wrapping number or fraction patterns.
- Once you get a match, either put the one with `/` char into the `result`, or the two other captures as separate items otherwise.

The regex par matches

- `(` - outer capturing group start (Group 1):
- `(\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?)` - Group 2: a number/fraction pattern: zero or more digits, an optional `.`, one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `/` char and then zero or more digits, an optional `.`, one or more digits
- `(?:\s+and\s+(\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?))?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `\s+and\s+` - `and` word with one or more whitespaces around it
  - `(\d*\.?\d+(?:\/\d*\.?\d+)?)` - Group 3: number/fraction pattern
- `)` - outer capturing group end.